# Click inside DirectX game while window is in background without bringing it to foreground

Tags: c#, winapi, user32, spy++

i'm currently trying to send input ( mouse currently, keyboard soon :D ) inside a DirectX game but i have no success.
From my current tests, i've only managed to get it clicked if the window is in front.
Here is the code ...

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace hots
{
    public static class Mouse
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        //[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        //private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lparam);

        // The SendMessage function sends the specified message to a window or windows. 
        // It calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return
        // until the window procedure has processed the message. 
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 SendMessage(
            IntPtr hWnd,               // handle to destination window
            int Msg,                // message
            IntPtr wParam,             // first message parameter
            ref Win32Api.tagWINDOWPOS lParam); // second message parameter

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 SendMessage(
            IntPtr hWnd,               // handle to destination window
            int Msg,                // message
            IntPtr wParam,             // first message parameter
            int lParam);            // second message parameter

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 SendMessage(
            IntPtr hWnd,               // handle to destination window
            int Msg,                // message
            IntPtr wParam,             // first message parameter
            long lParam);            // second message parameter

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 SendMessage(
            IntPtr hWnd,               // handle to destination window
            int Msg,                // message
            IntPtr wParam,             // first message parameter
            IntPtr lParam);            // second message parameter

        public const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
        public const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        public const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        public const int WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021;
        public const int WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006;
        public const int MK_LBUTTON = 0x0001;
        public const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
        public const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x0020;
        public const int HT_CLIENT = 1;
        public const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046;
        public const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        public const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
        public const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;
        public const int WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x0086;
        public const int WM_IME_SETCONTEXT = 0x0281;
        public const int WM_IME_NOTIFY = 0x0282;
        public const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
        public const int WM_CAPTURECHANGED = 0x0215;
        public const int WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008;

        public static void Click(IntPtr mainWindowHandle, Point location)
        {
/*            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_NCHITTEST, IntPtr.Zero, 105 | (568 << 16));
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_SETCURSOR, (IntPtr)0x00422A84, 0x02000001);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_MOUSEMOVE, IntPtr.Zero, 105 | (568 << 16));
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_MOUSEACTIVATE, mainWindowHandle, 1 | (WM_LBUTTONDOWN << 16));
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_MOUSEACTIVATE, mainWindowHandle, 1 | (WM_LBUTTONDOWN << 16));
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            var postChange = new Win32Api.tagWINDOWPOS()
            {
                cx = 0,
                y = 0,
                x = 0,
                cy = 0,
                flags = SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE,
                hwnd = mainWindowHandle,
                hwndInsertAfter = (IntPtr)0x00580E3C
            };


            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, IntPtr.Zero, ref postChange);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            var postChange2 = new Win32Api.tagWINDOWPOS()
            {
                cx = 105 + 1,
                y = 568,
                x = 105,
                cy = 568 + 1,
                flags = SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | 1800,
                hwnd = mainWindowHandle,
                hwndInsertAfter = (IntPtr)0x00580E3C
            };


            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, IntPtr.Zero, ref postChange2);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_ACTIVATEAPP, (IntPtr)0x00000001, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_NCACTIVATE, (IntPtr)0x00000001, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_ACTIVATE, (IntPtr)0x00000002, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_IME_SETCONTEXT, (IntPtr)0x00000001, (IntPtr)(1 | (0xC000000F << 16)));
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_IME_NOTIFY, (IntPtr)0x00000002, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_SETFOCUS, (IntPtr)0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_KILLFOCUS, (IntPtr)0x00232B2A, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_IME_SETCONTEXT, (IntPtr)0x00000000, (IntPtr)(1 | (0xC000000F << 16)));
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_IME_SETCONTEXT, (IntPtr)0x00000001, (IntPtr)(1 | (0xC000000F << 16)));
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_SETFOCUS, (IntPtr)0x00232B2A, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_IME_SETCONTEXT, (IntPtr)0x00000001, 0x0641);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_IME_NOTIFY, (IntPtr)0x00000002, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_SETFOCUS, (IntPtr)0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_SETCURSOR, (IntPtr)0x00422A84, 0x02000001);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)0x00000001, 105 | (568 << 16));
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, (IntPtr)1, 105 | (568 << 16));
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_CAPTURECHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            PostMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_MOUSEMOVE, (IntPtr)0x00000001, (IntPtr)(105 | (568 << 16)));
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            PostMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_MOUSEMOVE, (IntPtr)0x00000001, (IntPtr)(105 | (568 << 16)));
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_CAPTURECHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            PostMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)(105 | (568 << 16)));
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_CAPTURECHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            Thread.Sleep(5);

            SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_NCHITTEST, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)0x02DE0ACF);
            Thread.Sleep(5);*/

            //SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)(105 | (568 << 16)));

            /*            Win32Api.PostMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_MOUSEACTIVATE, mainWindowHandle,(IntPtr) (1 | (Mouse.WM_LBUTTONDOWN << 16)));
                        //mouse activate ?
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        Win32Api.PostMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_ACTIVATE, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(0 | (0 << 0)));
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        Win32Api.SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, (105 | (568 << 16)));
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        Win32Api.SendMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, (105 | (568 << 16)));

                        Win32Api.PostMessage(mainWindowHandle, WM_ACTIVATE, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)(0 | (0 << 0)));*/

            //PostMessage(mainWindowHandle, Mouse.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE, mainWindowHandle, (IntPtr)(1 | (Mouse.WM_LBUTTONDOWN << 16)));
            //PostMessage(mainWindowHandle, Mouse.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero,(IntPtr)(72 | (568 << 16))); // 72 568 x | (y << 16)
            //Thread.Sleep(50);
            //PostMessage(mainWindowHandle, Mouse.WM_LBUTTONUP, (IntPtr)72,(IntPtr)(72 | (568 << 16)));
        }
    }
}
```

Spy++ logs:
[Log 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqV1v.png)
[Log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvaDC.png)

I've tried to recreate each Sent/Post, no success.
Maybe i'm missing some vital info ? :D

Comment: I cannot recall, how many times I have posted this, in the hopes that I do not have to post it again: [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). Period. The same underlying principles apply to mouse input. Besides, a game is most likely not interested in window messages to handle input. It's more likely using Raw Input, or DirectInput, or XInput. Anyway, the vital piece of info you are missing is this: You cannot do what you hope to do.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. After some research i've found this: http://www.geekhideout.com/iodll.shtml which could help but only on x32 machines. Got any other idea on how this could be achieved? I got that it could not be done through Post/Send but, impossible is quite a hard word.

Comment: Of course you can implement your own driver, that injects input that is indistinguishable from genuine input. That, however, is still dispatched by the foreground window. A driver won't magically inject input for a background thread to pick up. For that to work you would need to inject code into the target process, and fight the anti-cheat system it implements. That, too, is possible. Still, you *grossly* underestimate the complexity of the task, and given your current skillset it is safe to call it impossible for you to solve.

Comment: @IInspectable I've managed to do it, to find out that it's pointless because of the anti-cheat system that detects it xD. There is no point in RE-ing the gguard so ima stop here. Thank you for the answers! :P

Comment: @ŞerbanNicuşor I'm trying to implement the same for a completely different DirectX application. Could you share the code/details of how you managed to do it?